# 12 or 16 column grid for a full width website?

Tags: css, grids, html, responsive-design

So I'm looking for the right answer for my grid system:

1) Should I use 12 or 16 column grid for a full width website similar to these websites:
http://xfinitytv.comcast.net
http://www.vevo.com

2) Can I use bootstrap for 16 column width

3) what are the challenges for a 16 columns grid vs traditional 12 column grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use 12 or 16

Sure. Use either one.

> Can I use bootstrap for 16 column width

By default Bootstrap is a 12 column grid. You could certainly modify it as you see fit.

> what are the challenges for a 16 columns grid vs traditional 12 column grid

Nothing, really. It's just a decision you're making to fit the needs of your particular layout. Both are equally valid. As would an 8 column grid or a 20 column grid or whatever...

Comment: thanks DA01. Could I have your thoughts on websites like xfinitytv.comcast.net and vevo.com that uses full browser width: can we tell they are using 12 or 16 columns? Which grid system and framework would work better for sites like that? thanks.

Comment: @PaulMartin there is no 'better'. It's just a decision you have to make based on whatever particular needs/wants you have.